# Constructing a compact set of real numbers whose limit points form a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I know this question has been answered before but I'd just like to verify that my solution is correct:

Consider a sequence $x_n = \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots $ so the sequence looks like $0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{15}{16}, \dots$

It's easy to verify that $| x_{n+1} - x_n | = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ for every $n$.

Define a sequence of sets $K_n = \{ x_n \} \cup \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty \{ x_n + \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} \}$.

Notice that each $K_n$ has limit point $x_n$ and none of the $K_i, K_j$ overlap by the third line (i.e. if $i<j$ then $k_i < k_j$ for every $k_i \in K_i, k_j \in K_j$).

Now define $K = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty K_n \cup \{ 1 \}$.

I claim that $K$ is our desired set.

By the Heine-Borel theorem $K$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Clearly $K$ is bounded (no member is less than 0 or greater than 1). I claim that $K$ is closed, i.e. it contains all its limit points. The limit points of $K$ are the sequence $x_n$ together with $1$ (because $x_n \to 1$), which are contained in $K$. Thus $K$ is compact. Finally, the limit points of $K$ form a countable set.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: That looks fine to me.